# WPF DetailView on DataGrid Left Click in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel, selecteditem

I have a datagrid that contains data of a user per row. now i want to show a detail/edit view if the user is left double clicking on a row in a new window.
i want to give the user id that is in the datagrid into the detail/edit window so that i can get the detail data from the user from the database.

how can i handle this? i think i must do one model and viewmodel for the datagrid view and one for the detail/edit view. But how can i send the uid form the selected item in the datagrid to the viewmodel from the detail/edit window?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the selected property of the datagrid to its viewmodel, and update the detail view viewmodel in the setter of this property.

Comment: i have declared a string property in my model and want to set the property with the uid content of the selected item. but now in the string property only stand: System.Data.DataRowView. is string not the corrext type for the selecteditem? i don't want the whole row, just one cell